# cpan install DateTime locks up

Tags: perl, datetime, cpan

I am trying to install DateTime on my Windows 10 machine and it keeps hanging up on me.  Here is the log file, any thoughts on how to fix it?

```
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for IPC::System::Simple
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  JKEENAN/IPC-System-Simple-1.26.tar.gz
  C:\Training\software\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for J/JK/JKEENAN/IPC-System-Simple-1.26.tar.gz
cp lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm blib\lib\IPC\System\Simple.pm
  JKEENAN/IPC-System-Simple-1.26.tar.gz
  C:\Training\software\perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
CPAN: CPAN::DistnameInfo loaded ok (v0.12)
Running make test for JKEENAN/IPC-System-Simple-1.26.tar.gz
C:\Training\software\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01_load.t .............. ok
t/02_exit.t .............. ok
t/03_signal.t ............ skipped: Signals not implemented on Win32
t/04_capture.t ........... 1/12
```

I am running this version of perl:

```
This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall

Binary build 2002 [299195] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Jul 20 2015 13:29:53
```

Comment: Just installed it fine on Win10, Strawberry Perl 5.30. Which Perl are you using?

Comment: Does [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) really depend on [IPC::System::Simple](http://p3rl.org/IPC::System::Simple)?

Comment: Holli, I just updated the comment with the version I am using.

Comment: ActiveState? ... I'm out (imaging DeGrasseTyson meme here)

Comment: Holli, I don't know one Perl from another, can you point me to some info on why one over the other?  I light to be enlightened ;)

Comment: Strawberry comes with a C-compiler that is already set up to work with Perl. ActiveState doesn't, so you have to set up a C yourself, which can  be tricky, or you have to rely on precompiled packages fromt their archive, which is never complete.

Comment: @choroba, It probably depends on autodie (directly or otherwise), and it depends on IPC::System::Simple for system and exec.

Comment: If I see it correctly, the test that hangs spawns a script `t/output.pl` and tries to capture its output. Maybe that requires  interaction on your machine. You can try to change `capture($output_exe)` to `system($output_exe)`, so  that all output goes to the console. Maybe that gives you better information.

Comment: Or go to the test directory, and try `perl  -e "system output.pl"`.